# how to create page layout on subsite

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-designer

i need to create a subsite for wsp export. But when i want to create a new page layout for my content type, it displays an error stating that the content type is not avaiable on the site collection. Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try to add the content type in pages document library 
Steps to be followed:
1)pages document library in the subsite 
2) click on libray and library settings from ribbon
3) check whether the required content types are available .if not add the required content types.